# CSS div box moves down a bit when text is put in

Tags: php, html, css, positioning

These are the css codes of my div, I'm making a slothead class div first and horizontally few slots.

```
div.slotshead{
    z-index:3;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #5f92d2;
    width: 130px;
    height: 50px;
    color: #003366;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'arial';
}

div.slots{
    z-index:3;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0fe;
    width: 45px;
    height: 50px;
    color: #003366;
    font-size:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'arial';
}
```

This is the code in them

```
echo '<h3>';
for ($i = 0; $i < 31; $i++) {
    echo "<div class=slotshead id=$i>";
    If($i==0){
        echo 'TIME';
    }
    echo "</div>";

    for ($j=0;$j < 23;$j++) {
        echo " <div class=slots>";
        If(($i==0)){
            $start = strtotime('8am');
            $k++;
            $tod = $start + ($k * 15 * 60);
            echo date('H:i A', $tod);
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }

    echo '<br>';

}
echo '</h3>';
```

here is the example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bZxT6/)

Here, The slots works fine but **slothead(div with 'TIME') moves a bit down**, why is that?
FYI, I tried `vertical-align=top;` But of no use...

Comment: Please make a fiddle so we can see the exact result you are getting.

Comment: show us a demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: i cannot take php codes to fiddle

Comment: @Mohammed: That's why I asked for the **result**. You can make a fiddle with the resulting HTML code.

Comment: I have created the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bZxT6/ just look that I couldnt understand whats going down for him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I feel this is what you are asking

in css add

```
h3{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

example

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bZxT6/1/)

Still you want to reduce mean see the following

```
html,body,h3{margin:0;padding:0}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bZxT6/2/)

Comment: @mohammedzameer if its your expected answer you can give up vote for this :)